# Range function is not working (invalid syntax)

Tags: python, loops, range

i want to create a little spambot to annoy my friends with but when i try to use the range function i get an error message.

the video i used:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qKQzT1Rehm8 

My code:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time

message = "Test"
keyboard = Controller()

time.sleep(5)

from num in range (100) :
 for letter in message:
        keyboard.press (letter)
        keyboard.release (letter)
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release (Key,enter)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

The error:

```
    from num in range (100) :
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

(the arrow is under the word "in")

Comment: Your problem is not the `range` function, it is that `from` should be `for`

Comment: Refer the docs, https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for

Answer (score 3):

Change `from num in range (100) :` to `for num in range (100) :`